# Standard Deviation of every pixel in an image in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, standard-deviation

I have an image stored in a 2D array called `data`. I know how to calculate the standard deviation of the entire array using `numpy` that outputs one number quantifying how much the data is spread. However, how can I made a standard deviation map (of the same size as my image array) and each element in this array is the standard deviation of the corresponding pixel in the image array (i.e, `data`).

Comment: create a numpy array with all the images. set the corresponding axis, while calculating standard deviation. will that be useful ?

Comment: Example 2D array and expected output would be helpful. Is the image binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slicing, given `images[num, width, height]` you may calculate std. deviation of a single image using `images[n].std()` or for a single pixel: `images[:, x, y].std()`